# php filter var returning a wrong result

Tags: php, filter-var

I wanted to use the php filer_var function but it's returning a wrong result, it seems that it doesn't take into account the range:

```
$v = 54;

$int_opts = array (

    'min_range' => 0,
    'max_range' => 24

);

if ( filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $int_opts) ) echo 'an integer';

else echo 'not an integer';
```

This shouldn't be an integer as 54 is not between 0 and 24, but it returns true and echoes "an integer".

What's the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, confirmed on PHP 5.3 on Windows. I can't see anything wrong with the syntax either. Is `filter_var()` really this buggy?

Comment: yes I'm on win7 x86 with PHP 5.3.5

Comment: Ah, it's indeed the syntax. See my answer.

Comment: PHP 5.2 Win7x32 - works fine.

Comment: @J0HN: x86 or x64 there is no x32 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "options" array needs to have a member named "options". From the [manual](http://php.net/filter_var):

```
$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'default' => 3, // value to return if the filter fails
        // other options here
        'min_range' => 0
    ),
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL,
);
```

you're not passing that so the behaviour displayed is okay.

Comment: This is very easy to get wrong - it should have been designed differently IMO.

Comment: ok I just found the problem. min_range and max_range should be put into an "options" array within the main array, if you recheck my original code you will find the mistake. and without even the "default" and "flags". thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = array(); 
$options['options']['min_range'] = 0; 
$options['options']['max_range'] = 24; 
$options['flags'] = FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL; 
var_dump(filter_var(54, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)); //bool(false)
var_dump(filter_var(21, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)); //int(21)
```

It works this way.

About `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL`:

Regards inputs starting with a zero (0) as octal numbers. This only allows the succeeding digits to be 0-7. According to this:

```
var_dump(filter_var(06, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)); //int(6)
var_dump(filter_var(09, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)); //int(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 5.3.8 purports to have fixed bug #47745 which meant that FILTER_VALIDATE_INT wasn't allowing a *minimum* integer.

The file you might want to check is ext/filter/logical_filters.c

```
void php_filter_int(PHP_INPUT_FILTER_PARAM_DECL) /* {{{ */
{
....
```