# How to use the options array in filter_input / filter_var

Tags: php

Does anyone know where I can find a list of possible keys for the options array in `filter_input()` or `filter_var()`?

I found an example [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#refsect1-function.filter-var-parameters) which has some possible  values as shown below

```
$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'default' => 3, // value to return if the filter fails
        // other options here
        'min_range' => 0
    ),
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL,
);
```

There was also a brief mention here: [How to add an option and a flag to filter_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077404/how-to-add-an-option-and-a-flag-to-filter-input)

I've searched high and low for a complete list with no luck.

**Edit**

Found this too: [php filter var returning a wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267060/php-filter-var-returning-a-wrong-result)

perhaps `array('min_range'=>'','max_range'=>'','default'=>'');` are the only possibilities?

Comment: The docs for filter_var say the options are specific to the filter itself. So the options are defined with each individual filter and examples documented in both places. What are you asking for?

Comment: thanks @MikeB , the answer below gave me what i needed, one of those days i think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All filters are documented

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Which leads to the following:

- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php

there is an "options" column in the "sanitize", "validate" and "misc" filters